# Telerik TestStudio test Ajax Response

Tags: telerik, functional-testing, telerik-test-studio

I would like to test an ajax response with the Telerik Test Studio > WebTest. However if I press a button on my webpage an jQuery function is called which sends information (2 parameters) the a controller. How can I check the Ajax response with Telerik Web Test? Do I need to use coding for this?
Thanks in advance for your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer in the telerik forum from an employee. So far it's **not** possible.

Link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/verify-ajax-xhr-response